# Average F1 Scores scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, score

I know there is [f1_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) metric to get all types of F1 scores (micro, macro, and weighted); however, I would like to be able to print micro averaged F1 score using [classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) of scikit-learn. By default, it seems to be returning weighted micro averaged F1. But I would like the micro averaged F1 in the `classification_report`. How do I do that?

Also, I know the difference in the formula between weighted and microaverages, but what are the instances where one would be preferred over other? And, what information do they convey?

Comment: The classification_report function isn't very configurable.. usually I just write my own functions for printing classification results - call the appropiate metric functions from sklearn.metrics and print their results..

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-learn's classification [report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) has micro averaged F1 score:

> Micro average (averaging the total true positives, false negatives and false positives) is only shown for multi-label or multi-class with a subset of classes, because it corresponds to accuracy otherwise and would be the same for all metrics